# void function cannot divide integers over 99

Tags: c++

When i give it 1011 and 100 i recieve this message:
**"Process returned -1073741676 (0xC0000094)   execution time : 4.425 s"**
I have got no idea for the life of me why if i give it 99 and 100 it works and it shows 0 but if i give it 100 it starts giving the message above, it should tell me how many of the numbers in n divide k.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void cate(int n,int k,int &x){
    int u=n%10;
    while(n){
        if(k%u==0) x++;
        n/=10;u=n%10;
    }
}
int n,k,x;
int main()
{
    cin>>n>>k;
    cate(n,k,x);
    cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: 0xC0000094 is "integer division by zero". You should be able to tell me why your program divides an integer by zero.

Comment: 0xC0000094 is `STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  [Demo](https://ideone.com/ZusZRr)

Comment: To create a minimal example, don't prompt for input. Just hardcode the input in the program.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> u=n%10;
> ```

When `n` is divisible by 10, `u` is zero.

> ```
> k%u
> ```

When `u` is zero, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: omg i swear i tried to use a if(u!=0) and it didn't work before but now it works Thank You

Comment: @CisPop there is always a danger that when you have multiple errors you throw away a correct solution because it solves problem one but not the unknown problem two (or two hundred).There are two really good solutions (and probably thousands not as good) based on not allowing more than one bug at a time. 1. Write very little code at a time and test it exhaustively before continuing so you rarely allow multiple bugs to get into the code and 2. back up your code and hack it apart until you have isolated the one bug you're trying to solve into a very small program that only has the one bug.